# Throwing three dice and analyzing results

Tags: probability

Three dice are being thrown.

$A$-exactly one of three numbers thrown will be $1$.

$B$-different number is thrown on each die.

What is:

1. $P(A\cap B)$
2. $P(A\mid B)$
3. $P(B\mid A)$
4. Are $A$ and $B$ independent on each other?

So my assumptions are as follows:

---

**1.** $P(A)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot (\frac{5}{6})^2\cdot 3=\frac{25}{72}\approx0.347$

$P(B)=1\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot4/6=5/9\approx0.555$

$\therefore P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)=0.347\cdot 0.555\approx0.193$

---

2.$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(B)}$ presuming, that $A$ and $B$ are dependent on each other

$P(B\cap A)=P(B).P(A)=\approx 0.193$ (we had it before)

$\therefore P(A\mid B)=\frac{0.193}{0.555}\approx0.348$

---

3.$P(B\mid A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$ presuming, that $A$ and $B$ are dependent on each other

$P(A\cap B)=P(B).P(A)=\approx 0.193$ (we had it before)

$\therefore P(B\mid A)=\frac{0.193}{0.347}\approx0.556$

---

4. $A$ and $B$ are dependent events

Am I right in my calculations?

Comment: For $A$, is it *exactly* one of the three numbers is a $1$, or *at least* one of the three numbers is a $1$?

Comment: What makes you say that $P(B\cap A)=P(B)P(A)$? Are the events independent? Why do you think so?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Exactly one of three numbers is 1

Comment: @drhab I guess I am wrong there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that $A$ is the event that *exactly* one $1$ shows up we have $P(A\cap B)=3\times\frac16\frac56\frac46$.

---

**Edit**:

Make the three dice distinguishable e.g. by giving them a number.

Probability that die$1$ shows $1$ and the other dice show distinct numbers in $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$ is $\frac16\frac56\frac46$.

Probability that die$2$ shows $1$ and the other dice show distinct numbers in $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$ is $\frac56\frac16\frac46$.

Probability that die$3$ shows $1$ and the other dice show distinct numbers in $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$ is $\frac56\frac46\frac16$.

This gives probability $3\times\frac16\frac56\frac46$ as probability that one die will show $1$ and the others will show distinct numbers in $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$. This event can be recognized as $A\cap B$.

Comment: Wait, could you explain a little? So is this correct: $P(B)=3\times\frac56\frac46$?

Comment: See my edit. No, $P(B)\neq 3\times\frac56\frac46=\frac{10}6>1$ but $P(B)=\frac66\frac56\frac46$ as you found out yourself.